# Adding Image to grid without using rowTemplate

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

```
columns: [{ title: 'Attain', field: 'Attain', width: '4%', template: '<img src="<#= Images/green.png  #>" />', sortable: true },]
```

I have written this line of code in colum for adding image.i placed green.png file in Images folder as well as stored green,red,yellow string names in database Attain column...now i want to check if dbstringvalue is grren then i want to display green image(if red,red image like)..
where should i write conditions code..is this possible to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Kendo Template may contain conditional logic. Here is an example:

```
columns: [{
  field: "Attain",
  template: "# if (Attain == 'red' ) { # <img src='red.gif' /> # } else # { <img src='green.gif' #}#
}]
```

More info about Kendo templates can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview).